# How to access cookies read with <img> tag, with $_COOKIE variable?

Tags: php

I have 2 servers viz. www.example.destination.com (destination server) and www.example.source.com (source server). I have some cookies set on destination server. I want to read those on source server. So, I have put `img` tag on source server like this:

```
img src="http://www.example.destination.com/" style="display:none;"
```

Now, I am able to read the cookies from destination server to source server.

I opened the URL www.example.source.com in my browser. I have checked it in my Chrome Developers tool -> Application tab. It is showing all the cookies from source server as well as destination server.

But, when I use `$_COOKIE` variable to access the destination server cookies in my source server php file, I am not able to get it.

So, how should I use the destination server cookies, that I have read it through `img` tag.

Comment: The browser will only send cookies back to the domain that set them. You can't read cookies you set on A on B.

Comment: Then, what's the use of reading those cookies, if I am not able to do anything with that?

Comment: Cookies are for persisting some data *for one domain.* They aren't meant to do anything cross-domain. In fact, that would be a giant security breach. That would mean virtually all your login cookies would be sent to Facebook and Twitter, since they're embedded in a ton of sites in one way or another.

Comment: Let me just stick `<img src="http://gmail.com/some/image">` and then use your cookie to read your email.

Answer (score 0):

Using an image source you can set cookies on your destination server, as you are basically sending a request.

However, to read it, you need access to that domain, redirect the user there, read it and pass it on another way back to your source server like a URL parameter or something.